# Searching for pattern with Dynamic Time Warping

Tags: pattern-recognition, time-series-analysis

I'm creating app that allows user to authorize by drawing dynamic gesture in front of camera (actually Leap Motion sensor, but that's not the point). Every person can save their own gesture as their password, so for every user I have a time series representing the gestures where single frame is an array of values that will allow me to recognize current frame shape. Now, the authorization process will look like this:

1. Person begins authorization process - camera starts recording frames, let's say, for five seconds.
2. After recording stops, the system has to somehow check if recording contains specific user gesture.
   I've decided to choose Dynamic Time Warping for this task.

I have few questions:

1. How to correctly search for this gesture? I have to allow person to draw the gesture faster or slower than the original, so should I cut the recording to multiple parts in multiple ways? Let's say first iteration cut by 10 frames, second by 12, third by 15 etc?
2. What is the right way to decide if the gesture is similar or not, what is the proper way to count the similarity (I don't want to compare it to other gestures because if person draws something completely different than any other gesture it will get classified somehow)? Also when I compare two exact same gestures, but one is faster (10 frames) and second slower (30 frames), the calculated distance is significantly lower than comparing the same gesture but with equal time. What is proper way to calculate "absolute" distance?
3. Currently I'm using Euclidean distance to calculate distance between each point between time series. Is it the right way?

I'm new to this topic so sorry if these questions sound stupid. I've searched for an example similar to mine, like find specific word in recorded sentence but couldn't find it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think there's a correct/right/proper or incorrect/wrong/improper way; there's just whatever works.  You might need to try some things and see how well they work.  Have you tried anything?  What have you found so far, and what specifically are you stuck on?  Have you searched for research literature on gesture recognition?  (e.g., with Google Scholar)  Please ask only one question per post.  When you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately in multiple posts.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cut the recording" or "cut by 10 frames".  You should be able to adjust DTW to deal with different speeds, if you want. Are you asking how to do that?  For your second frame, presumably you could normalize by the number of frames; have you tried that, and does it solve the problem?  I'm confused by what you mean by using the Euclidean distance, when you are using DTW.

Comment: Sorry for multiple questions in one post, I will remember it. I've tried comparing cut gestures. I have set of 15 files, where every gesture has 3 samples. When I compare them, I can see that for the same gesture distance is lower than for totally different gestures, so that works pretty well. What I mean with Euclidean distance, is that when we are calculating the cost while filling up matrix: cost := d(s[i], t[j]),
for me the cost equals Euclidean distance between these two points as they are multi-dimensional.

Comment: I doubt we can tell you whether Euclidean distance is appropriate without knowing what the vectors represent (i.e., what they are measuring).  I suspect all of this is too broad for a single question and it should be split up into smaller pieces.  Stack Exchange might not be the best fit for "how do I approach this entire project?", it's a better fit for "how do I solve this one specific issue I ran into when doing my project?".

Comment: As comparing single gestures with similar lengths works fine for me, what I'm stuck on is situation where I have a recording of length let's say 500 frames, and I have to find specific gesture within it. If the record (let's say hand twist) lasts 30 frames in original, the recording can contain this gesture faster or slower, let's say in range of 15 - 50 frames. I don't know what is the correct way of extracting samples from long recording to compare to my example, and to find (or not) the exact gesture. I've searched for literature but couldn't find anything that helps with my problem.